# How to nicely implement generic sorting in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to brush up on my C++ templating, and I'm running into the following issue. I'm implementing some basic in-place sorting methods, which I want to work for various types of data containers that can be indexed, and the elements of which can be compared. Specifically, the methods should work for both plain arrays, `std::array`, `std::vector`, etc. For some methods this is rather straightforward, like insertion sort:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void insertion_sort(T& data)
{
    if (std::size(data) < 2)
        return;

    for (int j = 1; j < std::size(data); ++j)
    {
        int i = j;
        while (i > 0 && data[i - 1] > data[i])
        {
            swap_index(data, i, i - 1); // basic helper that swaps data at two indices
            --i;
        }
    }
}
```

However, for some methods, I also need to know the actual type of the elements stored in `data`. An example is merge sort: I need to allocate some scratch space to be used for copying stuff around. I tried something like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void mergesort(T& data)
{
    typedef decltype(*std::begin(data)) inner_type;
    inner_type* scratch = new inner_type[std::size(data)];
    ...
```

but that just gives me errors like "error C2528: 'scratch': pointer to reference is illegal".

In C# I'd just use something like `where T : IComparable<T>`, and have a parameter of type `IList<T>`, which seems to be closer to what I want to achieve: have a type T that is comparable, and as parameter some indexable collection of Ts. What is the "proper" way to achieve this with C++ templates? Or should I use something other than templates here? I want to sort the container in place, so I don't think I want to use something like iterators.

Comment: Have a look at the declaration of [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) for a generic sorting interface.  Note that for scratch space `decltype(*iterator)` will be the element type.

Comment: The standard library has a convention of providing `T::value_type` for containers, but that won't help you with your requirement for this to work with "plain arrays" unless you create another template wrapped by the shown one and/or create a specialization. You may find that all roads lead to something that looks very much like _iterators_.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood iterators as being used only for enumeration. I woud accept an answer that explains how to do a basic sort with iterators. Otherwise I can self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the error message `inner_type` is a reference not the value type you are looking for. The following works for me (C++14 is required).

```
#include <type_traits>

typedef std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::begin(data))> inner_type;
```

Comment: While this possbly explains how to get rid of the specific error I was encountering, that was not actually my question.